# Laravel function to blade

Tags: php, string, function, laravel

I want a help to change this function of a model in my project cause it returns an array like this ::   [{"Package_Name":"Excel"}] i need only the string "EXCEL"

**Code in model**

```
public function getUserSeminars(){


        $seminar = Seminar::select('Package_Name')
            ->join('Home_StudentPackages','Home_StudentPackages.hsp_PackID','=','Home_Packages.Package_ID')
            ->join('Home_Students','Home_Students.home_id','=','Home_StudentPackages.hsp_homeStudID')
            ->where('Home_Students.home_id','=',$this->home_id)
            ->get();

        return $seminar;



    }
```

**blade**

```
 @foreach($users as $i=>$user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i+1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_firstname }} </td>
                <td>{{ $user->getUserSeminars() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->getUserRights() }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
@foreach($users as $i=>$user)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i+1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_lastname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_firstname }} </td>
                <td> 
                  <ul>
                    @foreach($user->getUserSeminars() as $seminar)
                       <li>{{$seminar->Package_Name}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                  </ul>
              
                </td>
                <td>{{ $user->getUserSeminars() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->home_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->getUserRights() }}</td>
```

Kind of some pseudo code, can't remember 100% correct sintaxis, but this should work.

Comment: first of all it worked like a charm second i want to double thank u for the bullets is this the <li> </li> ?

Comment: Yes, i guessed that being the lists a seminar you would like to list them all.

You are welcome ;)